# How to tile HTML elements from left to right using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a website with some tiled HTML elements (tables), which are tiling left-to-right. I need the tables to be tiled from right-to-left, as the content of the tables is in Arabic. A picture of the current format is linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqMzi.png).

Comment: Why tables? Just use inline-blocks that are flex-containers for a column of (original, gloss) elements, and let`dir="rtl"` handle the layout? Or if you don't need fancy formatting, just `<ruby>`?

Comment: @Amadan No, I specifically need to use tables for my implementation. This is not my final product.

Comment: @Amadan These tables are inline-blocks, but where would `dir=rtl` be applied?

Comment: @Amadan The <ruby> tag does not fit my purpose, as I need this page to support being printed.

Edit: `dir="rtl"` in the attributes for my `<body>` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment: Make the container of the inline-block elements right-to-left; then reset the English elements back to left-to-right.

```css
.glossed {
  direction: rtl;
}

.glossed > span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.glossed table {
  text-align: center;
}

.glossed tr + tr {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="glossed">
  <span><table>
    <tr><td>(ar) We worship</td></tr>
    <tr><td>(en) We worship</td></tr>
  </table></span>
  <span><table>
    <tr><td>(ar) you alone</td></tr>
    <tr><td>(en) you alone</td></tr>
  </table></span>
</div>
```

I put the direction directives in CSS for convenience, even though it is more common to have it as an HTML attribute (`dir="rtl"`) since it normally pertains to the content, not style.

Apologies I can't write Arabic, but the parentheses should make it obvious which order is being observed in each line.

Comment: The English and Arabic are in the same table, and should be handled together, with the container having its `dir` attribute set to `rtl`.

Comment: The Arabic part would inherit the `rtl` direction from `.glossed`; the English part will have its direction reset to `ltr` by `.glossed tr + tr`. But, as I added in the answer, you can put `dir="..."` explicitly into the markup, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this comment in the html beginning tag

And also use this styling in the css files
table {

```
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir="rtl"` in the attributes for my `<body>` made the direction of the tiling right-to-left.